# Using a 24 volt ac relay with a 16 volt ac doorbell circuit

Tags: relay

I have recently purchased a doorbell camera for the front door. It has the ability to ring my current doorbell but I use an intercom system with an electronic chime module. After watching many you tube videos and doing research I have determined that I must use a relay between the doorbell button and the chime module. The intercom system uses two (2) 16 volt AC transformers that are hidden behind the intercom which I would like to use to power the doorbell circuit and relay. However there are no 16 volt AC relays, only 12 V or 24 V. I could purchase a 24 Volt AC transformer, but there is no way to hide it inside the intercom master station and so it would look unsightly, and I prefer not to go that route.

Can I use the 16 V power supply with a 24 V relay, which would be 75% of the relay's rated voltage? This would not be a constantly energized relay, but only a momentary contact closure to trip the relay and complete the circuit to ring my intercom's doorbell chime. I feel this would work, but I'm checking with those who should know if there might be any problems or unforeseen consequences?

Comment: What does the relay data sheet say about the pull-in voltage?

Comment: 24Vac transformers can be hidden and don’t have to fit inside

Comment: Search for Omron's G6B-1114P-US-DC20 relay. That's a 20 V and closer to your 16 V need.

Comment: My post was about an AC Relay. Several have suggested a 20V DC relay or a circuit using a bridge rectifier for a DC Relay. Doorbell circuit use AC not DC.

Comment: Just to clarify: Your doorbell button is **just a passive button**, not an electric circuit that energizes when you press it, correct?

Comment: For a one off you just need to try it. The stated pull-in voltage in the datasheet is (hopefully) the lowest guaranteed by the manufacturer, not the lowest one you will encounter on a real specimen.

Comment: The word passive means it performs no action. So that is not correct. It works like any doorbell button...it does energize the circuit when pressed.

Comment: I watched another you tube video where a 24 Volt AC relay was used with a 16v AC transformer with the same circuit and use that I'm using. The you tuber tested numerous 24v AC relays and they all work fine. So for those who are scratching their heads on my behalf, I'm quite sure I have my answer. It will work. Thanks to those who offered help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

### Use a multi-voltage relay

The good news is that you're not stuck with single-voltage relay coils; a RIBU1C's low-voltage coil is rated for anywhere from 10-30VAC, for instance.  That, a plastic "handy box" with ½" KOs on it, and some wirenuts and cableclamps, will get you what you need.

Comment: Great minds think alike.  Advantage of this solution is that all the components are ul listed and packaged well. The underlying relay can probably be bought for a few dollars on an electrinics supply shop website

Answer (score 0):

Addition of a bridge rectifier and a filter capacitor would yield an open-circuit DC voltage, higher than 20 V, to energise a 24V DC relay.

[image]

Comment: This'll yield about 20VDC BTW

Comment: The voltage would be (16 * 1.414) - 1.4 = 21.2 V. It would definitely work, with the 'must-operate' voltage of a  relay  generally being not greater than 80% of its rated coil voltage (in this case 24 * 0.8 = 19.2 V).

Comment: Yeah, it'd work but it'd be a bit tight (I was counting the diodes as a ~1V drop as that's more typical for 1N400x type diodes)

Comment: The key phrase in my earlier comment is 'not greater than', which means that a relay could operate at a voltage even lower than that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a 12VAC Relay with Resistor in series to drop the Voltage by around 2-3 Volts to make it save to use with the Relay.

Or if you are feeling extra bold you could just use a 12VAC Relay that can handle up to ~14VAC and it should work just fine if it is only used as a momentary contact. But i wouldn't recomend it :)